# Series Question Complicated

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^n \sin\left(\frac{9}{n}\right)$$

Diverges or Converges ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: after taking away the first couple terms, this results is a direct application of the [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) as the function $\sin(x)$ is increasing between $0$ and $\pi/2$